# javac is not working even after setting the path in windows xp

Tags: windows, javac

Friends I couldn't access java in my xp even after i set the path

i set the path as set `path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin"`
It doesn't work in xp But it is useful in my windows 7 System
Don't know why
Please answer me
I also set path variable in the environment variables tab.But that doesn't worked for me
Still my `javac` command says javac is not recognised external or internal command.
So please help me

Comment: have you open a new command prompt after change in variable ?

Comment: Have you downloaded the correct java files first? if not then you can't direct it to any files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First follow these steps

```
Start -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced
Click on Environment Variables, under System Variables, find PATH, and click on it.
In the Edit windows, modify PATH by adding the location of the class to the value for PATH.
If you do not have the item PATH, you may select to add a new variable and add PATH as the name and the location of the class as the value.
Close the window.
Reopen Command prompt window, and run your java code.
```

now Run `where java`. this should return java path up to `java.exe`

If still you are having issues leave a comment

Answer (score 2):

Run this command in Command Prompt/CMD

```
set path="%path%;c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin"
```

If you already have a instance of terminal opened, you'll have to close it and re-open for work. Make sure this path `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin` is valid and has `javac`.

Answer (score 1):

1>First check if java is really installed in your PC.
You can do this by going to 
C drive->Program Files->Java

Inside java you should have two folders
1. jdk
2.jre

2> copy the path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin
(jdk1.7.0_25 is the jdk version you have installed as you mentioned)

3>Go to advanced system settings and click on Environment variables

4>Click on new and you will have two fill the variable name and variable value.
 type in " PATH " (without the double quotes and in CAPS) in the variable name
and paste the copied path in the variable name field.

5>Now open a new command prompt and type javac.
You should see a list and not the error you mentioned.

Another way..but this way is only a temporary solution since once you close cmd you will have to set path again. 
You can even set path= (paste the path you copied after the equals sign)